# iOS custom scrollable tab view like in android

Tags: android, objective-c, ios, user-interface, tabview

I want to realize **iOS tab view** like in **android** (Look at screenshot below)
Is there any ready open source iOS **libraries** doing this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want a `UITabBarController` to make use of the tabbing functionality (traditionally iOS tabs appear at the bottom of the screen, not the top as in Android), and within each tab you want to provide a scrollable view, which in iOS is called a `UIScrollView`.

You should go down this route, of implementing with the native `UITabBarController` and `UIScrollView`, as these will give a native iOS look. If you try and make it look too much like the Android version it will look like an Android app, which is against the iOS view guidelines.